# Extra div causing the image height not scaling properly (display: flex)

Tags: html, image, css, flexbox

I took the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42269484/divide-a-full-screen-width-height-section-into-3-rows). The code is working well but when I added an extra `div` to wrap the `div` with class `fullwidth`, the images height does not scale equally depending on the height of the screen.

This is how it looks originally:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.fullwidth {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.repeat-x {
  flex: 1;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.bg-1 {
  background-image: url(http://oi65.tinypic.com/28v4p6u.jpg);
}

.bg-2 {
  background-image: url(http://oi65.tinypic.com/28v4p6u.jpg);
}

.bg-3 {
  background-image: url(http://oi65.tinypic.com/28v4p6u.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="fullwidth">
  <div class="repeat-x bg-1">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="repeat-x bg-2">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="repeat-x bg-3">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

After wrapping `fullwidth` with another `div` :-

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.fullwidth {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.repeat-x {
  flex: 1;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.bg-1 {
  background-image: url(http://oi65.tinypic.com/28v4p6u.jpg);
}

.bg-2 {
  background-image: url(http://oi65.tinypic.com/28v4p6u.jpg);
}

.bg-3 {
  background-image: url(http://oi65.tinypic.com/28v4p6u.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div id="newid">
  <div class="fullwidth">
    <div class="repeat-x bg-1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="repeat-x bg-2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="repeat-x bg-3">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `height: 100%` to the `newid` container - this allows the `flexbox` to inherit the `height` of the document.

See demo below:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

#newid {
  height: 100%;
}

.fullwidth {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.repeat-x {
  flex: 1;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}

.bg-1 {
  background-image: url(http://oi65.tinypic.com/28v4p6u.jpg);
}

.bg-2 {
  background-image: url(http://oi65.tinypic.com/28v4p6u.jpg);
}

.bg-3 {
  background-image: url(http://oi65.tinypic.com/28v4p6u.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div id="newid">
  <div class="fullwidth">
    <div class="repeat-x bg-1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="repeat-x bg-2">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="repeat-x bg-3">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can choose one of these to enlarge the `#newid` to the whole height of the current viewport:

```
#newid {
  height: 100vh; /* this is how you do it in 2017 */
  height: 100%;
}
```

**For reference:** I can highly recommend this post if you wan to dive deeper into css units: [CSS Units - What is the difference between vh/vw and %?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039979/css-units-what-is-the-difference-between-vh-vw-and)

Comment: `100vh` only works when you explicitly want it to be the same height as the viewport - which is generally not desired if your container is nested within another container of partial height.

Comment: Thats true but it is not the case here as @kukkuz said: "the images height does not scale equally depending on the **height of the screen.**".

Comment: Yup, I just thought it'd be best to be explicit about it in case someone browsing sees and thinks "ooh, 100vh is the fancy new replacement for 100%!". Then again, if they don't follow your link they probably won't read the comments either, soooo...

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your css:

```
#newid {
  height: 100%;
}
```